# Calculating the determinant of an iterationmatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Let $C_\omega = (I-\omega D^{-1}L)^{-1}((1-\omega)I+\omega D^{-1}R)$
>   then $\det(C_\omega) = (1-\omega)^n$
>
> (Where $C_\omega\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $R$ is upper triangular, $L$ is lower triangular and $D$ is a diagonal matrix)

Could someone explain why this is the case?

I know:

$$\begin{align}
\det(C_\omega) &= \det(I-\omega D^{-1}L)^{-1} \cdot \det ((1-\omega)I+\omega D^{-1}R)\\
& = [\det(I-\omega D^{-1}L)]^{-1}\cdot \det((1-\omega)I+\omega D^{-1}R)\\
& = \ldots?
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after staring at it some time, I managed to see why.

Since $L$ is a lower triangular matrix, $R$ is an upper triangular matrix. Then 
$$\omega D^{-1}L\text{ is lower triangular}$$
So $I-\omega D^{-1}L\text{ is lower triangular}$ is lower triangular with 1's on the main diagonal which means it's determinant is 1.

The same reasoning holds for the second part, but now $1-\omega$ resides on the diagonal, which results in a determinant of $(1-\omega)^n$.